# Why does requests.get() is giving me the information in Spanish?

Tags: http, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to request the weather from Google for an specific place at an specific time. When I get the response the text is in Spanish instead of English. Ie. instead of "Mostly cloudly" I get "parcialmente nublado". I'm using the requests library and BeautifulSoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=weather+Nissan+Stadium+Nashville+TN+Thursday+December+29+2022+8:15+PM"

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")

clima = soup.find("div",class_="tAd8D")
print(clima.text)
```

Output

jueves
Mayormente nublado
Máxima: 16°C Mínima: 8°C

Desired output:

Thursday
Mostly cloudy
Maximun : x (fahrenheit) Minimum x(fahrenheit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that Google associates your IP address with a primarily Spanish-speaking region and defaults to giving you results in Spanish.

Try specifying English in your search string by adding `hl=en`:

```
https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=my+search+string
```

Comment: Yes, genius ! Thank you, this solves the problem. But can you help me change the temperature from Celsius to Fahrenheit ?

Comment: @FedeOrtiz A quick tip for how to use the site: If an answer is good, use the up arrow to tell other people that it's good. If the answer also completely solves your problem, there's a separate mechanism to "accept" it. And finally, if you have another follow-up question, ask that question in a separate post. I might be able to save you some time on that last point by suggesting that you just add the word "fahrenheit" to your google search string.

Comment: Thanks ... this is my first question and I don't have enough points to use the up arrow, as soon as I have 15 points I'll give this user an upvote.